# Copying file from windows mobile 6.5 to desktop computer using c#.net on LAN(WIFI)

Tags: windows-mobile, network-programming

I am using this C#.Net code to copy file on network from my PDA to Desktop computer

System.IO.File.Copy(@"\abc.txt", @"\servername\abc\temp.txt", true);

every thing is going on fine, but every time i am copying a pop up appears asking user,password,domain name and then copying is successful..

my question is can i implicitly pass user-name,password and domain name from code so that pop up should not appear every time..

any code snippets is appreciable thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You need to programmatically do NTLM authentication. I've still not spent the time to port this to managed code, but [here's the native solution](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2005/02/08/NTLMDomainAuthentication%c4%b0nCE.aspx) which you can port over.

Comment: Fixed the link - there seems to be a bug in the SO "add link" stuff that stripped out some characters.